# Input box 100% width, with label to the left

Tags: css

I'm trying to have a fluid input box with 100% width, while having the label floated to the left.  Here's what I currently have:

```
.left {
  float: left;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

<form>
    <label class="left">Name:</label>
    <input class="left" id="name" name="name"/>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

This works, however it drops down below the label.  If I use a parent div to assign the floats, then it doesn't span 100%.  Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to get the input box and the label on the same line? If you have an input box of 100% the container's width, there's no room for a label on that same line, so it would be impossible to do so.

Answer (score 23):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/r2769/ *(resize the window)*

**CSS:**

```css
.left {
    float: left;
}

.left2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 4px 0 10px
}
.left2 input {
    width: 100%
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<form>
    <label class="left" for="name">Name:</label>
    <span class="left2"><input id="name" name="name" /></span>
</form>
```

An explanation of the method [is here](https://colinaarts-com.herokuapp.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden#making-room-for-floats).

Comment: Yeah, it's really very useful :)

Comment: Thx for the smart idea illustrated on a nice jsfiddle.

Comment: Do you know how to do this the other way around, with the text on the right? Bit trickier than it seems.

Comment: @mpen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938900/how-can-i-put-an-input-element-on-the-same-line-as-its-label/6938990#6938990 / http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Khmhk/782/. I usually use `display: table` for this now. Can also do it with flexbox.

Comment: @thirtydot Cool. I used the table variant. Thanks!

Comment: The link is down.

Answer (score 3):

I recently found out about calc in css:

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

this can be used to solve this problem: [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/H62xW/)

HTML:

```
<div class="setting">
    label
    <input class="s2"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.setting {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.setting .s2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
    width: calc(100% - 184px);
}
```

Comment: works, but not supported across all modern browsers (3 versions back). Breaks, most notably in Safari 5